# spSiteDataQuery vs KeywordQuery

Tags: 2013, search, keywordquery, spsitedataquery

What is the difference between `spSiteDataQuery` and `KeywordQuery`?

My goal is to search only a number of specific lists by their list GUID.  The specific lists I need are both Generic List and Libraries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in the two is how they retrieve the desired data.

`SPSiteDataQuery` executes a CAML Query towards the SharePoint Site Collection.
Think of how you would use CAML Query to gather `SPListItems` from an `SPList` and scale it to a `SPSite` / `SPWeb` level.

`KeywordQuery` utilizes the SharePoint Search Service engine to retrieve data from the Indexed results.
Using the `KeywordQuery` is often recommended in most cases because it is faster to retrieve already indexed items.